# How to get objects after CoreData Context merged

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data

I tried to save data and merge with CoreData and multi-thread for iPhone app.
But I can't get managed objects in the main thread after merging.

I wrote code just like this:

```
[managedObjectContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                       withObject:notification
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didMerged:) withObject:objectIds waitUntilDone:YES];
```

So I tried to pass objectIds to get NSManagedObject instances in the main thread which were generated in another thread. At first I tried "objectWithId" method but it generated fault objects. Then I tried "existingObjectWithID" method but it generated objects partly and others were nil with following Error:

```
[Error] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133000 "Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 133000.)"
```

What is wrong? Is there any way how to retrieve all objects by objectIds after merging in another thread?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

There are two types of object ids. Before you save a NSManagedObject it has temporary object id. After saving, it will get its final id. So you may use the wrong id...

Read Managed Object IDs and URIs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectid

Answer (score 2):

It seems your context merge failed.

[developer documentation on error 133000](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectReferentialIntegrityError)

> NSManagedObjectReferentialIntegrityError         = 133000
>
> NSManagedObjectReferentialIntegrityError
> Error code to denote an attempt to fire a fault pointing to an object that does not exist.
> The store is accessible, but the object corresponding to the fault cannot be found.
> Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later.
> Declared in CoreDataErrors.h.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.

Hmm... In another thread, I can save data without any error. How can I merge them to the context in the main thread well without #133000 error?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to unroll your errors.  Change the output to:

```
NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
```

That will give you a lot more information.

Second, if you are working with a single context in multiple threads you are doing it wrong.  You need to review the documentation on Core Data and threading.  The basic rule is: One Context Per Thread; Period.  If you need to manage data across multiple threads look into watching the save notifications from the background threads on the main thread.  I would suggest reviewing my articles on the Mac Developer Network for examples of this.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check the error in detail. Yes, I created contexts for each thread.